# how to get a tag value from a razor component

Tags: asp.net-core

Given that I use Visual Studio 2022 and I am referring to an ASP.NET Core Web App.
I have a page that displays a leaflet map, in it there is a function that loads many markets with the related popups.
The aim is to click on a button located in the market pop-up and open a modal which, depending on the ID of the clicked market, accesses the DB and loads the details.
This function passes the market id to the modal:

```js
  function markerOnClick(e) {
      var exampleModal = document.getElementById('Vertice')
      exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          exampleModal.querySelector('#Lbl_Id_vertice').textContent = e.target.ID;
      })
  }
```

The function transfers the ID to a label of the modal written on a razor component

```html
label <label id="Lbl_Id_vertice">@ID</label>
```

And so far it works.

And now I come to the question: I don't know how to recover the value of the ID attributed by the javscript function to be able to manage it in the C# code of the razor component

Be gentle, given my little knowledge of the language I was unable to find any other way to transfer the variable to modal

Comment: Are you looking to post that value to the server in a form submission?  Use it in an AJAX operation?  Something else?  Currently you're simply updating the content of that `<label>` in client-side code, it's not entirely clear what you want to do with it from there.

Comment: I need that value server side.
I have to use it with the C# of the razor component in order to extract data from the db

Comment: *"I have to use it with the C# of the razor component"* - Are you referring to the C# logic on this same page?  Because that doesn't really make sense.  The C# code executes to render the page, then the page is sent to the browser.  It sounds like you want to use data from the browser to continue to render the page that's already been rendered and sent to the browser.  You may be misunderstanding the differences between server-side and client-side code?

Comment: Thank you for your time dedicated to me. Are you referring to the C# logic on this same page? I certainly can't always distinguish server-side code from client-side code.
In my case, on the client side the function attributes the ID to the label before the modal is sent to the browser, then I saw that this function (Razor C# code)  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    SomeStartupMethod();
    await SomeStartupTask();

}
it is executed before loading the model, so I thought I would use it to complete the valorization of the variables present on the model

Comment: Unless there's some additional complexity not included in the question, what you have is simply a misunderstanding of [server-side code and client-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/328193).  The server-side code can't use a value that won't exist until after the server-side code has finished executing and sent the resulting page to the browser.  There is likely some way to accomplish whatever it is you're actually trying to do, but the approach you've taken and are asking about here is not how to do it.

Comment: Now the problem is clear to me. 
Thank you
Can you suggest me a way
What I would like to do is this:
A button starts a modal by sending an ID to it. The modal receives the ID, and using server-side functions of the razor component retrieves the data it displays on the modal

Comment: If you want to dynamically fetch data from the server in client-side code then the technology you're looking for is called "AJAX".  The JavaScript code would make an AJAX request to a server-side endpoint, providing any data needed, and the server would return JSON data to the client.

Comment: To pass the ID from the js code to the C# code in a Razor component, you can use a hidden input field to store the ID and then access it in the Razor component.

Comment: Thank you Rena for your time
I tried but couldn't access the input field.